# Ampersand in c++ range based for loops

Tags: c++, reference

Here is the code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const unsigned int max_chars = 100;
    char buffer[max_chars];
    std::cin.getline(buffer, max_chars, '\n');
    unsigned int count = 0;
    for (auto c : buffer) {
        if (c == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    std::cout << "Input: ===========" << std::endl;
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number of chars ==" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::dec << count << std::endl;
    std::cout << "==================" << std::endl;

}
```

This is adapted from some example code in a c++ text book deliberately dealing with c-style strings, so bear with me.

So I tried two versions of this, one with `for (auto c : buffer)` and the other with `for (auto &c : buffer)`. Both seemed to work. The question is, what is the difference then?

Comment: In the first case you get a copy of every element, in the second you get a reference to the element.

Comment: @qed is your question "what a reference is" or "what is the difference in this particular type"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use a link, you work directly with the elements of the container. Otherwise - with a copy. Try this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    vector<int> a(n);
    vector<int> b(n);
    for (auto &key : a) key = rand()%10;
    for (auto key : b) key = rand()%10;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << a[i];
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << b[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first one (no &) is a value, the second one (with &) is a reference. A reference, as its name implies, "references" a value, similar to the way a pointer "points" to a value.

Try adding `c = 'x';` after your if statement and trying both ways to see the difference here.